# How to apply useRef() in React TS?

Tags: typescript, react-hooks, react-tsx

Goal:
Get value from the textbox when you click on the button

Problem:
The value don't display in the console.

```
"Uncaught Error: Function components cannot have string refs. We recommend using useRef() instead"
```

How do you apply useRef() in this context?

Stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-mcn4jd?file=index.tsx

Info:
*Newbie in react TS

Thank you!

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {

  function test() {
    // Get the value and display it at consol
    //var name = refs.mytext.value;
    
    var element = document.getElementById("ddddd");


    console.log(element);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="text" id="ddddd" ref="mytext" />
      <button onClick={() => test()}>Add</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could also use useRef<HTMLInputElement | null>(null) for better type support

```
import React, {useRef} from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';


function App() {

  const mytext = useRef<HTMLInputElement | null>(null);

  function test() {
    // Get the value and display it at consol
    //var name = refs.mytext.value;
    
    var element = document.getElementById("ddddd");


    console.log(mytext.current?.value);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="text" id="ddddd" ref={mytext} />
      <button onClick={() => test()}>Add</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useRef` to create a ref, and then pass that ref to the HTML using curly braces, like so

```
function App() {
  var mytext = useRef(null); // Create ref with no initial value
  function test() {
    var name = mytext?.current?.value; // Get ref value

    console.log(name);
  }

  // Pass to HTML
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="text" ref={mytext} />
      <button onClick={() => test()}>Add</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I get a error in VS code saying "  > 10 |     TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'. at  "var name = mytext.current.value;"

Comment: It is warning you that mytext.current might be null; use `mytext?.current?.value` instead.

Answer (score 0):

In functional components you have to use `ref={mytext}` instead of `ref="mytext"`

```
import React, {useRef} from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';


function App() {

  const mytext = useRef<any>(null);

  function test() {
    // Get the value and display it at consol
    //var name = refs.mytext.value;
    
    var element = document.getElementById("ddddd");


    console.log(mytext.current?.value);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="text" id="ddddd" ref={mytext} />
      <button onClick={() => test()}>Add</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: In VS code. I get a error saying "TS2339: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'never'." at "    console.log(mytext.current?.value);"

Comment: then use a any type here `const mytext = useRef<any>(null)`